# Как вызвать функцию с request без ошибки?

Tags: python, django

```
def decorDef(request):
    return print('lolo')


decorDef(request)
```

При вызове данной функции выдаёт ошибку: nameerror name request is not defined.
Я понимаю, что она говорит - не подключён request, но по факту, он вполне работает если убрать `decorDef(request)`. (Мало ли, я напомню, что request используется в веб-приложениях (я работаю с джангой), и скорее всего в этом дело. Но не понимаю, как как исправить.) Благодарю.

Comment: Вы неправильно понимаете. Ошибка говорит о том, что в вызов функции вы передаёте неопределённую переменную.

Comment: Книгу по Python почитай сначала. Для чего тебе в django данная функция? Я воще не понимаю...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В строке `decorDef(request)` , вы должны не просто указать переменную параметра, а указать аргумент, например `decorDef('То что вам нужно')`, теперь функция работает корректно, но если вам например не нужна передача аргумента, то просто не указывайте ничего в параметре:

```
def decorDef():
    return print('lolo')
decorDef()
```

И на всякий случай, аргумент необходимо передавать если вам нужно сделать примерно так:

```
def decorDef(request):
   print (request)
decorDef('g')
```

Comment: Зачем ему было отвечать? Пускай сначала книгу дочитает

Comment: Если ничего не передавать, то выдаст ошибку: TypeError: decorDef() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request',

Comment: (случайно нажал энтер), а если передать что-то в (не request), то всё сработает, благодарю!